# some two values and add to next value pyramid calculation

Tags: python, php

i need some solution in php  or python calculation in pyramid form  need loop until two digit value remains

i now this form not for code creation but am trying many things but not find solution of my problem

here is input

```
12345
```

need output like this add value to next value remove (0)

```
12345
3579
837
21
```

Explain : now am explain output formula
first line in input   you can ad first two value from input
`1 + 2 and 2 + 3  and 3 + 4 and 4 + 5` = 3579

2nd line is 3579

```
3 + 5 = [8]  = 5 + 7 = (12) and add 1 + 2 = [3] and 7 + 9 = 16 and 1 + 6 = [7] = 837
```

3rd line 837

```
8 + 3 = (11) = 1 + 1 = [2] and 3 + 7 = (10) 1 + 0 = [1] = 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$value == $string1` before printing instead of after, so you don't print the matching value.

```
<?php 
    
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_REQUEST['convert']);          
    $string1 = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_REQUEST['convert']);
    echo $string;
    echo "<br>";
    $formatted = implode(' ',str_split($string));
    echo $formatted;
    echo "<br>";
                
    $count = mb_strlen($string);
    
    for($loop=0;$loop<$count;$loop++)
    {               
        $value='';          
        $j=$count-1;
        $total=$count/2;
                        
        for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++)
        {
            $value .=$string[$j];
            $value .=$string[$i];
            $j--;
        }
        if ($value == $string1) {
            exit();
        }
        if($count%2==0)
        {
            $value;
            $formatted = implode(' ',str_split($value));
            echo $formatted;
        }
        else{
            $value=substr_replace($value, "", -1);
            $formatted = implode(' ',str_split($value));
            echo $formatted;
        }
        echo "<br>";
        $string=$value;         
    }           
}
    
?>
```

Comment: sir again read my question matching value is 2nd problem main problem you can f understand function output and my need output am edit my question code working perfect but opposite my need you just focus on my need output and actual output  please sir    @Barmar

Comment: You need to explain the logic in each step.